# Posterior of Inverse Wishart distribution with a subset of data observed

Tags: posterior, conjugate-prior, wishart-distribution, conditional

Suppose:

\begin{equation}
x_1\in \mathbb{R}^{p_1}\\
x_2\in \mathbb{R}^{p_2}
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{equation}
x \sim \mathcal{N}(
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}; 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1\\
\mu_2
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} \Sigma_{12}\\
\Sigma_{21} \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix})
\end{equation}

where $(\mu, \Sigma)$ has Inverse-Wishart-Conjugate-Prior:

\begin{equation}
p(\mu, \Sigma) = \mathcal{N}(
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1\\
\mu_2
\end{bmatrix}; 
\begin{bmatrix}
M_1\\
M_2
\end{bmatrix}, 
\kappa 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} \Sigma_{12}\\
\Sigma_{21} \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix})
\mathcal{IW}(
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} \Sigma_{12}\\
\Sigma_{21} \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}; 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Psi_{11} \Psi_{12}\\
\Psi_{21} \Psi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}, v)
\end{equation}

the marginal of $\mu$ and posterior predictive of $x$ can be found here: [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf) equations (256 and 258)

The conditional distribution $p(x_1 | x_2)$ can also be solved using the conditional of the $T$-distribution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution

Lastly, the posterior of $p(\mu_1 | x_1$) can also be found using the marginals of the normal and Inverse-Wishart and following Murphy's text (eq 256).

However, I am struggling to find:

\begin{equation}
p(\mu_2 | x_1)
\end{equation}